# Windows recursively delete folder and all contents

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying find a way to delete a specific folder name and delete all of its contents in Windows. So my D: drive has a 100 folders, inside each of these folders are sub folders called folder1, folder2, folder3, etc. I want to be able to run a command at the root of D: that will search through each 100 folders and delete say folder3, and folder9 and all of its contents.

```
RD /s /q "folder1"
```

The above command doesnt like to search through subdirectories.

Anyway of doing with with CMD or do I need a .vbs script or something?

Thanks!

Comment: `rd /s` WILL delete subfolders... but only if they're empty. if there's a single file anywhere in the tree, the directories above that file's location will not be touched. Note that this includes hidden/system files as well.

Comment: @MarcB Yes, however I want to be at the root of my D drive and have it search for all 'folder1' and 'folder9'. I dont want to have to go into each directory and run this command everytime, I want to have it recursively look in each folder

Comment: `for /r %f in (d:\) do rd /s /q "%f"`

Comment: @MarcB - Not true. It will delete the entire tree, even if one of the sub-folders contains files or additional folders. It prompts for confirmation unless the /q option is used, as the OP has specified.

Comment: Ah. so you want to nuke any folder whose name is "folder1", anywhere it might appear in the tree? the for loop'd work on that, just add in an `if` type test to check if %f==folder1

Comment: Yes, also is there a way to specify 2 folders so it would nuke both at the same time? What would be the command for that?

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to remove all folders named "folder1" and "folder9", regardless where they appear? Or do you only want to remove "folder1" and "folder9" that are grand-children of the root directory?

Comment: whereever folder1 and folder9 appear in D:\My Files I want them and the folders contents to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FOR` command to go through the list of subfolders from a given location and run commands on each subfolder. e.g.:

```
for /F "delims=\" %%I in ('dir /ad /b <someFolder>') DO (
    cd "<someFolder>\%%I"
    rd /S /Q "folder1"
    rd /S /Q "folder3"
)
```

It would get the list of folders in *someFolder*, and delete the directories named "folder1" and "folder3" from each subfolder.

Comment: It would be so much simpler using `for /d %%I in ("somefolder") do...`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OPs comments, I believe the following will do the trick:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /s /ad "d:\My files"^|findstr /ie /c:"\folder1" /c:"\folder9"'
) do if exist "%%F" rd /s /q "%%F"
```

Comment: When I run the code I get the following `for /F %F in ('dir /b /s /ad "D:\My Files"|findstr /ie /c:"\folder1" /c:"\folder9"') do if exists "%F" rd /s /q "%F"` Looks like its not liking the space in the first folder name.

`if exists "D:\My" rd /s /q "D:\My"`

Comment: @nutt318 - oops, I forgot the critical "delims=" option. All fixed now.